# Groovy return-by-reference conundrum

Tags: java, groovy, dsl, mop

I am writing a DSL in Groovy to hack BASIC scripts. I am thinking about how to handle BASIC arrays.

It seems easy enough to use MOP to handle something like:

```
100 LET X = A(5)
```

I would dynamically declare the A closure when A is DIMed, and this A closure would return a value based on its arguments. But not so simple to handle:

```
110 LET A(5) = Y
```

As I cannot return-by-reference from Groovy. Other than parsing for whether the A(5) is an lvalue or an rvalue, can someone think of a way round this?

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy answer, and keep in mind that even if you solve this problem, you're still going to have to deal with BASIC conditionals (e.g. "IF a = 10 then ...").  You can probably get what you need with judicious use of AST transformations, but likely that's no easier than writing your own custom parser.  In other words I think you're doomed, and should do something other than write BASIC scripts if at all possible.

Comment: Oh I am making a fair bit of progress - see http://cartesianproduct.wordpress.com/2012/06/17/some-basic-i-can-now-run/ - regular expressions are powerful things!